# CSS pseudo content selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to determine the style of a div by going by what is in it. If the content is '0', it should have color: red, and if not, fall back to the usual color.

I've found there used to be :contains(value), but that doesn't exist anymore. Is there any replacement I can use for this in css?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could read the `innerText` of the `div`, if all you're looking for is a single character. You could do that with a small bit of Javascript. But setting the class with server side code is usually the sanest approach.

Comment: @KristianVitozev this is not a duplicate of that question at all.

Comment: In the existing CSS there is only a possibility to display red '0's in `div`s that have no content at all: http://jsfiddle.net/cKnFC/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. If CSS was going to have a content selector, it would have kept `:contains()`.

For what it's worth, [jQuery implements `:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector), so if you're using it already you can apply styles with it instead.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the answer. Thanks anyway!